# Submitting job position dialog does not disappear, gets submitted anyway

Tags: bug, developer-story

In Chromium 58.0.3029.110 (with potential interference from uBlock Origin 1.12.4):

When submitting a `Position` in `Developer Story` page: The dialog does not disappear when confirming it and an error pops up in the developer console.

`story.en.js?v=58ff4a48f52b:1 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at Object.get (story.en.js?v=58ff4a48f52b:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (story.en.js?v=58ff4a48f52b:1)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)
get         @ story.en.js?v=58ff4a48f52b:1
(anonymous) @ story.en.js?v=58ff4a48f52b:1
i           @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith    @ jquery.min.js:2
y           @ jquery.min.js:4
c           @ jquery.min.js:4`

I realize this stack trace might not be particularly helpful, but rather safe than sorry.

Out of frustration I've submitted the `Position` a bit more than once. Therefore, many entries appear on my `Developer Story` page. I cannot remove any of them. Pressing `Delete` does not trigger any network activity.

New `Positions` can be submitted without problem after I reloaded. They can also be removed. In contrast to the existing ones, which can't be removed.

Comment: Hi @Ole, I have been able to remove one of the duplicated positions from your profile using the same UI. Can you please confirm me that you still can't remove items, and tell me the id of one of these? (you can see the id by inspecting the "Delete" link using the browser developer tools)

Comment: I cannot remove them, still.

3044556
3044557
3044578
3053950
3053952
3053953
3053954
3053955
3053956
3053957
3053958
3053959
3053961
3053962
3053965
3053966
3053968
3054028

Comment: Hi @Ole, I deleted the duplicate positions from your profile. Please let me know if there are still items you cannot delete and want deleted.